# Delta Table : Does Time Travel with Timestamp as of and Version as of retrun same results?

Tags: azure, pyspark, restore, delta-lake, time-travel

While doing time travel for delta file, does the "timestamp as of" and "version as of" return same results? or is anyone of them more preferred or accurate or performant?

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp as of: This allows you to query the state of data at a specific point in time. The timestamp must be in yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS format. This is useful when you want to see the state of the data at a particular moment.

Version as of: this allows you to query specific version of the data. Each operation that modifies a Delta Lake table creates a new table version. This is useful when you want to audit operations, rollback a table , or query a table at a specific version.

If you are interested in the state of the data at a specific point in time, use the timestamp. If you are interested in the state of the data after a specific operation, use the version.